# Strongly Typed DataSet Return All Columns When Selecting a Single Column

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using a `Strongly Typed Dataset` as DAL.

I want to return a single column from my table for that i wrote the code as

```
SELECT DISTINCT Floor
FROM            Room
WHERE        (Building = @Building)
```

But when i previewed the data, it shows me all the columns of the table with Null Value and the column with primary key has -1 value.

This condition raise an Exception when i link this query to a ComboBox ..

```
cmbFloor.DataSource = da.GetFloorByBuilding(cmbBuilding.Text)
cmbFloor.DisplayMember = "Floor"
```

Error:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null,     unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

Comment: Are you certain that the constraints you have on your typed DataSet are the same constraints in your DB table?

Comment: no that is not the case?

Comment: The constraint is because the strongly typed dataset create a class with the tablename and has all the constraint in the database.. but i have removed the constraint like primary key from the Dataset file.. but that too didn't worked in my case..

Comment: You should add a query that returns a scalar value to your TableAdapter. Do not use the query-type that returns multiple records because the TableAdapter uses the specified table-model then. But apart from that, if you want to use it as DataSource for a ComboBox, why do you select a single value?? Instead you should use it's [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) and [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) properties.

Comment: No it will return a single column but with many rows... i want to use the same table adapter that i have created for a specific table

Comment: I've edited my last comment. You should use ValueMember and DisplayMember to define the key and whats being displayed, but select all columns as in your default query.

Comment: If you can see my sample code above, you will find that i have used `Dispay Member`, the thing is that you have not understood my question.

Comment: da.GetFloorByBuilding will return a single column but in the structure of RoomTable from the Dataset which will show all the rest columns as NULL and filling NULL Values into the RoomID column throws the exception since it is primary key set and primary key value cannot be null.. Now i want to resolve this problem by only return the column that i have mentioned in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each table in Strongly Typed Dataset is  stored as a Class. When a query returns a table value or any scalar value. The Dataset returns an class object which contains all properties.